# functions with integer intervals - discrete math help

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Here's a question that I'm trying to figure out:

Let a, b, c, d be integers with $a \leq b$ and $c \leq d$. How many different functions exist with domain $[a..b]$ and codomain $[c..d]$?

So far, I know that the domain maps the codomain, and that $[a..b]$ can be rewritten as $|[a..b]| = b - a +1$. Therefore, $[c..d]$ can be rewritten to $|[c..d] = d - c +1$.

The number of functions can be determined (if we consider A the domain and B the codomain) as $B^A$.

Does it then follow that the number of functions, and the answer to this question, is $(d-c+1)^{b-a+1}$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The total number of maps from a set of size $m$ to a set of size $n$ is $n^m$. You can prove prove this as follows: suppose the first set is $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ and the second set is $B=\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}$. To get a function $f\colon A\to B$, you need to first decide what $f(a_1)$ is. There are $n$-choices for this. Next, you need to decide what $f(a_2)$ is, which has $n$-choices again. So a function $A\to B$ is the same thing as just picking an element of $B$ once for each element of $A$. The total number of functions is then $|B|^{|A|}$, or $n^m$.

Also, as a small note, usually when people write "interval" they mean an interval of real numbers, which is an infinite set. The closed brackets $[a,b]$ is shorthand for the set $\{x:a\le x\le b\}$.